# Should summation of int64 array and int pass an int64 type check?

Tags: python, numpy

I seem to have stumbled upon some weird code behavior and am not certain, whether this is expected or a bug. When I add an int derived of a time object a type check to int64 fails.

I can narrow it down to literally the multiplication of a float onto the time object:

```py
import numpy, time

# base check works
ts = numpy.arange(10, dtype=numpy.int64)

print(type(ts[0]), " and should be numpy.int64 : ",  end = "")
if isinstance(ts[0], numpy.int64) : print("Check OK!")
else : print("Check FAILED!")

# time object works
ts = numpy.arange(10, dtype=numpy.int64) + int(round(time.time()))

print(type(ts[0]), " and should be numpy.int64 : ",  end = "")
if isinstance(ts[0], numpy.int64) : print("Check OK!")
else : print("Check FAILED!")

# float itself works
ts = numpy.arange(10, dtype=numpy.int64) + numpy.int64(round(1e9))

print(type(ts[0]), " and should be numpy.int64 : ",  end = "")
if isinstance(ts[0], numpy.int64) : print("Check OK!")
else : print("Check FAILED!")


# for some reason the multiplication of both does not work
ts = numpy.arange(10, dtype=numpy.int64) + int(round(time.time()*1e9))

print(type(ts[0]), " and should be numpy.int64 : ",  end = "")
if isinstance(ts[0], numpy.int64) : print("Check OK!")
else : print("Check FAILED!")
```

My output is :

```
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check OK!  
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check OK!     
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check OK! 
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check FAILED!
```

The first checks above work, as they should, since to my understanding the dtype of ts should remain int64 (and it does obviously).

The last check however fails, EVEN THOUGH the dtype is indicated as int64. I do not understand why.

I ran the code on a python3.6.8 with numpy1.16.4. The machine is 64bit, so the natural int should be 64bit as well, but either way this should not matter, since I specifically state int64 in the numpy array (AFAIK).

I actually have 3 different machines, with different python versions (python 3.5.3 & numpy 1.16.2) and (3.6.8 and 1.16.2) yield the same failed check. One of them wasn't even set up by myself, but is a managed system. I believe this is not related to my local installation.

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: so why doesn't it work for me then ?   
  
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check OK!  
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check OK!  
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check FAILED!  
<class 'numpy.int64'>  and should be numpy.int64 : Check FAILED!

Comment: I can reproduce with numpy 1.16.4 and python 3.6.7 on an ubuntu machine.

Comment: we are using windows machine, can't reproduce the error. it is working fine for me.

Comment: Since this is reproduced by others, I raised a [bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14476) with the numpy developers